Error integrating with OpenSearch when using spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch
I have a test project with the following configuration:

spring boot 2.7.18
spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch
opensearch 2.6.0

The connection to OpenSearch is configured like this:
@Configuration
class OpensearchConfig: ReactiveElasticsearchConfiguration() {
    val httpHeaders = HttpHeaders()
    httpHeaders.add("Content-type", "application/json")

    override fun clientConfiguration(): ClientConfiguration {
        val config = ClientConfiguration.builder()
            .connectedTo("localhost:9200")
            .usingSsl()
            .withDefaultHeaders(httpHeaders)
            .withBasicAuth("admin", "admin")
            .build()

        return config
    }
}

I'm trying to save a simple entity:
val isIndexExists = opensearch.indexOps(Person::class.java).exists().awaitSingle()

if (!isIndexExists) {
     opensearch.indexOps(Person::class.java).create().subscribe()
}

opensearch.save(Person(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), name))
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .subscribe()

And I got the following error:

org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: status:
200, [es/indices.exists] Missing [X-Elastic-Product] header. Please
check that you are connecting to an Elasticsearch instance, and that
any networking filters are preserving that header.; nested exception
is java.lang.RuntimeException: status: 200, [es/indices.exists]
Missing [X-Elastic-Product] header. Please check that you are
connecting to an Elasticsearch instance, and that any networking
filters are preserving that header.] with root cause

I didn't find an answer in the documentation whether spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch supports OpenSearch, so I had a question - maybe I'm configuring the connection to OpenSearch incorrectly? Or do I need to use opensearch-rest-client instead of spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch?

Spring Data Elasticsearch is built against Elasticsearch servers using Elasticsearch client libraries.
You might want to check out spring-data-opensearch https://github.com/opensearch-project/spring-data-opensearch
